# Routing table and splitting traffic in Omnet++

Tags: networking, routes, simulation, network-traffic, omnet++

I am new to Omnet++ 4.3, I have a WMN network and I want to send traffic through two shortest paths, from one of my client nodes to two ONU(wgRouter).

First I want to know how can I find the 2 shortest paths, is it possible to run the network and find the first shortest path through one of the wgRouter and save the routing table and then turn off that wgrouter and then run the model again and find the second shortest path through another wgrouter and again save the routing table ,then turn on the off wgRouter, use both routing tables in initialization part ( I dont know how can I use them both in one time, please let me know if you know) and run the model ?

let consider that we found the two shortest path through two wgRouters, Now how can I split the traffic equally between both of them?

any information would be very useful for me. Thanks.